# multi-column index and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a mysql database with 7 million rows hosted on an aws rds micro instance.

I am doing this sort of queries:

```
SELECT
  `id`, `address`, `property_type`, `rooms`,
  `published`, `size`, `net_rent`, `gross_rent`,
  `purchase_price`, `original_id`
FROM (`properties`)
WHERE
  `postcode` IN ('1000', '1001', '1002', '1003',
                 '1004', '1005', '1006', '1007',
                 '1010', '1011', '1012', '1014',
                 '1015', '1017', '1018', '1019')
  AND `published` < '2013-01-09'
  AND `property_type` IN ('Apartment', 'Apartment with terrace',
                          'Attic', 'Attic flat / penthouse',
                          'Loft', 'Maisonette', 'Studio')
  AND `sale_or_rent` = 'rent'
LIMIT 50
```

And thus I created an index like that:

```
| properties |          1 | listing       |            1 | postcode      | A         |       25091 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| properties |          1 | listing       |            2 | published     | A         |     2333545 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| properties |          1 | listing       |            3 | property_type | A         |     3500318 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| properties |          1 | listing       |            4 | sale_or_rent  | A         |     3500318 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

Everything is fine so far. The problems arrise when I try to add ORDER BY published DESC (30"+ for one query).

Is there anyway to have an efficient ORDER BY published DESC knowing that I also need published to be in a WHERE clause?

Comment: Prefix your query (with the order by) with EXPLAIN, and run it and add the result to your question. Guess it's not finding your index usable for teh order by and doing a full sort, but it's a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try putting 'published' first in the index